# C# reading from text file (which has different data types) to get sum of numerical values

Tags: c#, sum

So I have a .txt file that reads as the following:

```
-9
5.23
b
99
Magic
1.333
aa
```

how would I then loop through it to get the sum of all numerical values, and leave the non-numerical values untouched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");
        double sum = data.Select( x => {double v ;Double.TryParse(x, out v);return v;}).Sum();
        Console.WriteLine("sum:{0}", sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read text file using `System.IO.StreamReader` and use `Double.TryParse` method to parse the numeric data.

Comment: Would Decimal.TryParse be a better option?

Comment: I think it depends on what you want result SUM type.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you can either:

- Use `int.TryParse`
- Use Regular Expresssion to match only integers.

Comment: That would leave out the 5.23 and 1.333.  The question is to sum numeric (not integer).